# SQL Server: only return data if count of one column is greater than another

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do:

If the total number of occurrences of a serial number in table `OITM` (`OITM.AssetSerNo`) is greater than the total number of occurrences of the same serial number in `RDN1` (`RDN1.SerialNum`), then I want to return a few fields from the `OITM` record with the matching serial number where the Asset Number `OITM.ItemCode` (PKey) is greatest.

The code I have is as follows

```
select 

oitm.itemcode as 'Asset No', 
oitm.itemname as 'Asset Description',
oitm.assetSerNo as 'Serial No'

from oitm
inner join rdn1 on oitm.assetserno = rdn1.serialnum

WHERE
OITM.itemtype = 'F'
and OITM.asststatus = 'A'

HAVING count(oitm.assetserno)>count(rdn1.serialnum)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error because the majority of my items are neither in a group by or an aggregate function. I'm not even sure the `HAVING` clause is the best way to approach the problem (in fact, I'm fairly sure that it's not).

EDIT: Sample data (I guess?)

OITM

```
ItemCode        ItemName        AssetSerNo        ItemType       AsstStatus
123             Object 1        QW                F              I
234             Object 2        ER                F              A
345             Object 3        RT                F              I
456             Object 4        TY                F              A
567             Object 1        QW                F              I
678             Object 5        YU                F              I
789             Object 3        RT                F              A
890             Object 1        QW                F              A
901             Object 2        UI                F              A
```

This is an item master list data record. A = active, I = inactive.

RDN1

```
DocID           Object Name     Serial Num 
1               Object 1        QW
2               Object 3        RT
3               Object 1        QW
4               Object 5        YU
5               Object 4        TY
6               Object 3        RT
```

This is a list of return records, for when the rented items return to the warehouse.

Expected output:

```
ItemCode        ItemName        AssetSerNo 
789             Object 3        RT
456             Object 4        TY
```

I need a list of all items where a return has been created, but the item has not been made inactive yet. I can't just do an inner join on RDN1 because I may have items that are returned, the item record is changed to I, but then it's sent back out and a new item record is created.

Comment: Post sample data and expected output.

Comment: That's the issue. I don't have any sample data. I'm essentially working blind here. I'll try and mock some up, though.

Comment: use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an option using some sub queries

```
SELECT 
    item.itemcode AS 'Asset No',
    item.itemname AS 'Asset Description',
    item.assetSerNo AS 'Serial No'
FROM
(
    SELECT
        oitm.itemcode,
        oitm.itemname,
        oitm.assetSerNo,
        COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY assetSerNo) assetSerNoCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY assetSerNo ORDER BY oitm.itemcode DESC) rn
    FROM
        oitm
    WHERE
        OITM.itemtype = 'F'
        AND OITM.asststatus = 'A'
) item
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        serialnum, COUNT(*) serialnumCount 
    FROM 
        rdn1 
    GROUP BY 
    serialnum
) serial ON serial.serialnum = item.assetSerNo
WHERE
    ISNULL(serial.serialnumCount,0) < item.assetSerNoCount
    AND item.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

20 different ways to do this and they are all right. Here is the way using most of your code and implementing an EXISTS() command.

```
select 
 oitm.itemcode as 'Asset No', 
 oitm.itemname as 'Asset Description',
 oitm.assetSerNo as 'Serial No'
from oitm x
WHERE
 EXISTS(
  select TOP 1 1 
  from oitm y
   inner join rdn1 z on y.assetserno = z.serialnum
  WHERE
   y.itemtype = 'F'
   and y.asststatus = 'A'
   and y.assetSerNo = x.assetSerNo 
  HAVING count(y.assetserno)>count(z.serialnum)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve! I've updated the question a bit (and am going to add a bit more). I'm new to SQL, and not familiar with the `EXISTS` tag. If I was pulling other information from another table as well, would I juts put it in the same `Select` and `From` at the start, before the `WHERE` and `EXISTS`? Can you tell me if the query you've given me should give the output like I put in the question?

Comment: The key, hidden slightly by the use of xyz table naming, is the `y.assetSerNo = x.assetSerNo ` at the end. This is getting records from the sub-select used in the exists() command only for the outer select. You could have use an `IN()` command or multiple nested selects and they would all return the same thing and in the same time (more than likely). And yes, if you need more columns, add them to the top select. This is your output.